# Print to PDF is different in excel depending on custom DPI

Tags: excel, pdf, printing, dpi

I was called in this morning to work on a tool that I had built in Excel a while back. The tool generates a report and then prints it to a pdf. The problem they called me in for was that for one user the line spacing in the PDF was off. It took me a while to figure out the cause of the problem. It was the DPI. The user who has trouble seeing the font had increased the font of Windows to 150% and for some reason that causes excel to export to pdf differently.

I know what the problem is but asking the user to change the DPI (forcing the user to log off), log back in, open excel and run my macro and finally change back the DPI is not a reasonable solution. I hope that there is a guru out there that will be able to help me find a solution. I don't mind adding VBA code to temporarily change the DPI while the program is running but I'm not sure how to do that or if its possible.

Thanks

For more clarification its windows 7 and the aspect I’m speaking of is if you go to change the resolution there is a link asking if you want to “Make text and other items larger or smaller”. The slider was changed from the defaulted 100% to 150%.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of an easy way of overcoming this problem. Something that you could try is to create an OLE application (in C#, VB.NET or C++ for example) that uses Excel internally just to open the file and export it to PDF. Then you can create a new user on the system and lunch this application from a batch file using the command [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx). 
Back in Excel again, you can lunch the batch file using the [Shell](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/shell-function-HA001228906.aspx) command.
The workflow would be:

1- Using VBA and the Shell function,invoke the batch file from Excel with the current file as parameter.
2- The batch file calls a custom application MyAppExportToPDF using runas and passes the current Excel file as parameter.
3- MyAppExportToPDF opens a new instance of Excel using OLE, loads the file, and exports it to PDF.

Since MyAppExportToPDF will run in a different user, the new Excel instance should also run under that user. The DPI settings under this user should be the ones you need.

Disclaimer: This is just an untested idea.

Comment: Your method would work from what I can see but I was unable to implement it for my user did not want anything outside of excel the file (The file gets sent back and forth between several users and they did not want to send multiple files). I tried to convince them otherwise but it seems that either I fix it within excel or it'll have to be an accepted bug.